# GaN Ripple with dropout to 0 volts on turn on

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, gan

I'm currently troubleshooting a GaN SEPIC converter that uses a non-synchronous control IC (LM5022), driving a GaN gate driver and a small GaN FET. The circuit is operating as expected however I'm noticing some fairly large ripple on the gate of the FET which doesn't seem right. The gate driver is located next to the GaN and should attract low parasitic inductance, however the LM5022 output to the gate driver is a 10mm trace.

Below is the schematic.

[image]

The gate signal on the FET is pictured below and the ripple in question, note the first ripple that presents like a complete dropout accompanied by fairly high ripple voltages that could possibly damage the gate. Where should I start digging for sources aside from exploring values for the RC across the Vds node and what could be causing this dropout?

[image]

[image]

Layout:

[image: layout 3D view top]

Comment: How are you probing the gate? At these kinds of time scales it's very easy for your scope to be lying to you.

Comment: Hey @Hearth, I'm using this method: https://community.element14.com/technologies/test-and-measurement/b/blog/posts/the-proper-way-to-use-a-scope-probe-for-high-frequency-signal-measurement

Comment: Please show layout.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams layout is here: https://imgur.com/a/tP7Svme

The LM5022 is on the other side of the board, about underneath L4

Comment: Is this a multilayer board? Why is drain poured around the driver? The switching loop is C8-D6-(C30, C31)-Q12-R61, a good layout for fast transistors is challenging in any SEPIC but it is especially loose here, which does not bode well for switching transients.

Comment: Those scope voltages don't look very serious at all.

Comment: Sorry the probe was set to 10X @Andyaka

Comment: Hiya @TimWilliams it's a 4 layer board with ground plane between the top and bottom layers

Comment: @AlexTurner you need to tell the scope you are using a 10x probe

Comment: I mean, "need to" is rather overstating it; just adding a note so readers know is fine.

Comment: So what do you mean by "dropout"? This isn't a linear regulator, and output regulation doesn't seem to be in question.  The ringing/oscillation on the rise/fall edges, is most likely visible throughout the circuit due to switching loop inductance.